# Google Play In-app Billing - list purchases

Tags: google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-services, billing, android-billing

I wish to get list of in-app purchases that I purchased but have not consumed.

Does Google Play provide such API?

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#QueryPurchases

```
Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
int response = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
if (response == 0) {
   ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST");
   ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
      ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE_LIST");
   String continuationToken =
      ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN");

   for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) {
      String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
      String signature = signatureList.get(i);
      String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

      // do something with this purchase information
      // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
   }

   // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
   // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
}
```